# a.i.TcpListener - Bind failed for TCP channel on endpoint [/0.0.0.0:9000] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: intellij-idea, akka

In my `IntelliJ`, `Scala`, `Play` application, I have suddenly started gettinng error when I build the code

```
a.i.TcpListener - Bind failed for TCP channel on endpoint [/0.0.0.0:9000]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

I am on `Windows10`. I found the process and killed it and that actually killed `IntelliJ` IDE itself!! So I don't think it was some other process using the port!

I even tried restarting the machine but that didnt' work either. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Some other process occupies the port on the machine. Try restarting the pc, check that it is not an antivirus/firewall issue. Try with antivirus/firewall disabled or make sure that IDE [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) IDE installation home and IDE process are excluded from the scan.

Comment: added the .Intellij folders as exception in Windows10 firewall and restarted the PC after that. But no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin point what went wrong but I uninstalled and re-installed IntelliJ. I had several IntelliJ directors in my home directory, probably created after updates. I removed all of them. Maybe I wasn't excluding the right directory from the firewall settings. Andrey's suggestion above is worth trying though